# Error with formatting dynamic values in a xml string python?

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to generate a xml string using python and I am passing dynamic values but for some reason I am getting a strange error. Can someone please advise what could I be doing wrong?

```
def zipcode_listing_detail_xml(zipcode, total_number_of_listing, rate):
    xml = """<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
    <zipcode listing-count = """ + str(total_number_of_listing) + """ average-daily-rate = """ + str(rate) + """>""" + str(zipcode) + """</zipcode>"""
    print(xml)
    return XML
```

This is how the XML looks

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
    <zipcode listing-count = 0 average-daily-rate = 0>M11</zipcode>
```

This is the error

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 30: AttValue: " or ' expected
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, the error tells you that attribute values should be quoted like listing-count=‘0’

Comment: @YannisP.- Yeah, but how do I add that in the dynamic XML that I created?

Comment: For the values you need quotes, e.g. `<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
    <zipcode listing-count = '0' average-daily-rate = '0' >M11</zipcode>`, double quotes are OK too.

Comment: You could place ‘ before and after “”” or use f-strings

Comment: @MarcelPreda- That is hardcoding the comma. I want to be able to do it through the dynamic XML that I am using to create

Comment: @YannisP. - Thank you so much. So silly of me to not put that ' before the "". Thanks it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code below should solve the problem with quoted values

```
def zipcode_listing_detail_xml(zipcode, total_number_of_listing, rate):
    xml = "<?xml version = \"1.0\" ?>\n<zipcode listing-count = \"" + \
        str(total_number_of_listing) + "\" average-daily-rate = \"" + str(rate) + "\">" + \
        str(zipcode) + "</zipcode>"
    print(xml)
    return xml

result = zipcode_listing_detail_xml("M11", 0, 0)
```

Here we escaped double quote using `\"` , but you can also use single quote `'` (no escape needed here), both quote types are valid for XML.